# SBT assembly skip some subprojects

Tags: sbt

I have an sbt multi module project which is configured for sbt assembly. In this project i want to skip the fat jar generation for sub projects that are not intended to be executable in order to speed the build up. But I'm not sure how this is done.

Answer (score 4):

If you use a build.sbt file you can disable the assembly plugin for a module as follows:

```scala
lazy val module = (project in file("module"))
  .disablePlugins(sbtassembly.AssemblyPlugin)
  .settings(
    ...
  )
```

This also works for the root module:

```scala
lazy val `project-name` = (project in file("."))
  .disablePlugins(sbtassembly.AssemblyPlugin)
  .aggregate(`module-1`, `module-2`)
  .settings(
    ...
  )
```

(Answer found thanks to @tobym 's comment in the other answer.)

Answer (score 2):

Just don't include the assembly settings in the submodules that don't require it.

For example, using sbt 0.13.5 and sbt-assembly 0.11.2, here is a multimodule project. If you run `assembly` in root, just the "app" project will be made into a fat jar.

`project/Build.scala`

```scala
import sbt._
import Keys._
import sbtassembly.Plugin.assemblySettings

object MyApp extends Build {

  lazy val root = Project("root", file(".")).aggregate(common, app)

  lazy val common = Project("common", file("common"))

  lazy val app = Project("app", file("app")).settings(assemblySettings: _*).dependsOn(common)

}
```

`common/src/main/scala/com/example/common/Hello.scala`

```scala
package com.example.common

object Hello {
  def hello(name: String): String = s"Hello, $name"
}
```

`app/src/main/scala/com/example/hello/App.scala`

```scala
package com.example.hello

import com.example.common.Hello._

object Main extends App {
  println(hello(args(0)))
}
```

Comment: But its an auto plugin, so I'm not adding the assembly settings to any project.

Comment: I'd like to know that too, basically root/assembly resolves to creating individual jar packages for all submodules instead of one root jar package including dependencies of all subprojects.

Comment: It basically enforces the assembly settings for each project present in build definition. There is a setting `assembleArtifact := false` but it doesn't seem to have any effect. It still assembles the project.

Comment: You can disable plugins with `(someProject).disablePlugins(sbtassembly.AssemblyPlugin)`

Comment: @tobym Your last comment probably answers the question better than your original answer, you might want to include it in the main answer as a first option. Anyway, it was most helpful to me, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the sbt settings **do** work, but you have to read the code to find the correct way to use them. I was able to accomplish what you want by setting:

```
assembleArtifact in packageBin := false,
assembleArtifact in assemblyPackageScala := false,
assembleArtifact in assemblyPackageDependency := false,
```